# Are Axis2 generated stubs thread-safe?

Tags: java, web-services, multithreading, thread-safety, apache-axis

Are client stubs generated from WSDL by Axis2 thread-safe?

Of course, "thread-safe" isn't necessary a rigorously defined term, so I'm at least interested in the following:

Are *different* instances of the same stub class accessible concurrently by different threads, with the same effective behavior as single-threaded execution?

Is a *single* instance of the same stub class accessible concurrently by different threads, with the same effective behavior as the same calls interleaved in some arbitrary way in single-threaded execution?

You may also wish to use the terminology described [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp09263.html) (and originating [here](http://books.google.ca/books?id=ZZOiqZQIbRMC&pg=PA208&lpg=PA208&dq=item+52+thread-safety&source=bl&ots=UZQY6qhK1-&sig=k9Td0NLzuEspPSEygh9D4_T3gxA&hl=en&ei=yiUwS-SVBYSLlAehsqiQBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CAwQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=item%2052%20thread-safety&f=false)) to discuss this more precisely.

Comment: I was under the impression that Apache Axis2 was being phased out in favor of Apache CXF: http://cxf.apache.org/

Comment: That may be, but my question still stands as I don't have the liberty of changing our underlying framework at the moment (someday, maybe:)...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm not sure about axis2, but at least axis1 generates non-threadsafe client stubs. I got the impression pretty much every other SOAP client was non-threadsafe as well. If I remember correctly the issue was with the XML parsing library being used in a non-threadsafe way by the client stub.

Using apache commons-pooling to pool the instances and using each one from one thread at a time worked well though.

Update: For Axis2, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-4357 (claims Axis2 is not threadsafe, by design)

Comment: To be clear, you mean that you cannot use the *same* instance from multiple threads, but using multiple instances (of the same stub class) from multiple threads is OK as long as there is no concurrent access to any given instance?

Comment: Yes. And apparently stub instances don't have to be bound to a certain thread either.

Comment: But the author below states that axis stubs are stateless, and therefore can be safely accessed from multiple threads concurrently:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950080/are-axis2-generated-stubs-thread-safe/1968188#1968188

Comment: Funny, this question has an answer claiming Axis2 is not threadsafe, with a JIRA issue to back it up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977997/axis2-generated-stubs-are-thread-safe links to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-4357

Comment: I've voted this answer up, primarily because it's not the fault of Stefan L that I now have a good amount of refactoring to do...

Answer (score 3):

I guess I'll try to answer my own question by providing some update on futher research I did.  It appears that by default older versions of Axis2 stubs may have been only "thread-compatible" (cannot make calls on the same stub instance concurrently from multiple threads - but calls to different instances is OK).

See for example:

http://markmail.org/message/3lu7x7pfo47vgnck
http://markmail.org/message/sljyf6lpecxqllgx

You may experience some socket leaks, and run out of sockets if you don't call cleanup/cleanupTransport, as per this thread and many related ones:

http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-3670

In some cases, at least the underlying HttpClient now seems to be thread-safe, but depending on how you generated your client, the entire stub might not be:

http://amilachinthaka.blogspot.com/2009/05/improving-axis2-client-http-transport.html

Answer (score 2):

These stubs are stateless allowing reuse of the stub instances. Can you please elaborate on the problem you are facing with Axis2. People usually recommend Xfire over Axis.

Comment: I thought XFire was defunct and folded into another project

Comment: You can call CXF as XFire2.0 , I am bit biased towards it :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer - can you comment on what level of thread safety is offered?  You can call any method on the same object from any number of threads concurrently and get the expected behavior?

I'm not experiencing any particular problem with Axis2 - just that we've created stubs using the framework and need to quantify the thread-safety level for such components.  This is (relatively) easy for the stuff you write yourself, but more difficult for the auto-generated stuff.

Comment: What is the data binding you are using..?

Comment: We are using XMLBeans data binding.

Comment: Have you used axis stubs in such ways, t.m. simultanous calls from multiple threads? The guy above stated that axis stubs are not thread safe.