# Using Thread.join() method

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to multi-threaded programming. I am getting unexpected behavior when using the join method. Sometimes both the threads give the same result, sometimes only one result is displayed and sometime the correct result is displayed. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String model = args[0];
        String property = args[1];
        String parameters = args[2];
        String wsdlPaths = args[3];
        int numServices = Integer.parseInt(args[4]);
        String[] parameter;
        getParameters(parameters, parameter);
        String[] wsdl;
        getWSDL(wsdlPaths, wsdl);       
        Thread[] t  = new Thread[numServices];
        ClientHelper[] nch = new ClientHelper[numServices];
        TestStub[] stub = new TestStub[numServices];
        TestStub.Experiment[] request = new TestStub.Experiment[numServices];
        TestStub.ExperimentResponse[] response = new TestStub.ExperimentResponse[numServices];            
        for (int i = 0; i < numServices; i++) {     
            stub[i] = new TestStub(wsdl[i]);
            request[i] = new TestStub.Experiment();
            request[i].setArgs0(model);
            request[i].setArgs1(property);
            request[i].setArgs2(parameter[i]);
            nch[i] = new ClientHelper(stub[i], request[i]);
            t[i] = new Thread(nch[i]);          
            t[i].start(); // When I moved this statement to the next loop just before the join method, the program behaved like a single threaded program and was working correctly.
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numServices; i++) { 
            try {
                t[i].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            System.out.println(t[i].getName());
            response[i] = nch[i].response;
            System.out.println("Response " + i + " : " + response[i].get_return());                
        }
    }
}


public class ClientHelper implements Runnable {
    TestStub stub;
    TestStub.Experiment request;
    TestStub.ExperimentResponse response;

    public ClientHelper(TestStub stub, TestStub.Experiment request){
        this.stub = stub;
        this.request = request;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            response = stub.Experiment(request);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance you can take your problem, and create a smaller testcase?   The first thing I see is that one of your threads could be throwing an exception and you would never see it, and as a result would have unexpected behavior. Inside your empty catch block add a print statement.

Comment: That *isn't* the code you're running. For example, this won't compile:  `String[] wsdl; getWSDL(wsdlPaths, wsdl);`. Please post real code.

Comment: @Jon Yes, this isn't the real code, I am running, I tried to strip the code as much as I can. The real code requires some model and property files and a web service which can execute those files. So you wouldn't be able to run it.
My main problem is 
    `for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        thread[i].start();
    }
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        thread[i].join();
        //output variable set by thread[i].
    }`
On different runs the variables printed out are different. Sometimes they are the same, sometimes only one of them is printed and sometimes none at all.

Comment: So simplify your code into something which demonstrates the problem *but will compile*. Otherwise you may very well have stripped out the problem. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints. My guess is that you have some shared state which you didn't intend, but if you can't give us any realistic code, we can't tell.

Answer (score 0):

Since the posted code will not compile, and it might simply be too large to deduce the root cause, I'll take my chances and hint on what might be going wrong.

Your code contains two for loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numServices; i++) { 
    ...
    t[i].start();
}

for (int i = 0; i < numServices; i++) { 
    t[i].join();
    ...
}
```

Your observation has deduced that

```
for (int i = 0; i < numServices; i++) { 
    t[i].start();
    t[i].join();
    ...
}
```

does not cause problems.

Well, that is because you are now serializing the process, and there is no concurrent execution at all. The only thing I can deduce from this, is that you are sharing state across threads, possibly in the `TestStub` or `TestStub.Experiment` arguments to the constructor of the Runnable. I can't state what is being shared unless there is code to execute, but this is most certainly the cause.

**Update**

After considering the statement `stub.Experiment(request);`, I would also suggest verifying if the (generated) web service proxy and the web service client framework are threadsafe as well. They might be publishing object references that might be used across threads and hence require explicit synchronization using appropriate locks. Sadly, there is no easy way to determine whether a library and set of generated classes are thread-safe.

Comment: Yes, I guess most probably there is a problem with `stub.Experiment(request);` BTW I am using Axis2 and generating the client framework by wsdl2java command.

Comment: It is likely, but to some extent, it appears that [using separate stubs in separate threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977997/axis2-generated-stubs-are-thread-safe) *might result* in a thread-safe implementation. Of course, this should not lead you to believe that no state sharing is occurring in your code.

Comment: @Rohit, is there a way you can publish the WSDL of the webservice? I could mock the service, and see if your client-side code is threadsafe or not.

Comment: I figured it out. There is nothing wrong with the code and since I was using different instances of the same stub class, it was a thread safe implementation. The problem was with the web service I had written. There were two web services and both of them were writing the result to the same file!!
Sometimes all you need is a new day.
Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

All your requests are using the same model and property. If they have some state - you'll get this behavior.

```
request[i].setArgs0(model);
request[i].setArgs1(property);
```

Comment: Yes, the model and property are supposed to be the same in all the threads (and they are only read by the web service) only parameters are supposed to be different between different threads.

Answer (score 0):

```
    t[i].join();
```

This does not do what you think it does! It "pauses" the main method! And it lets the main method wait for t[i] to finish. After that the main method resumes that loop.

Comment: Yes, I want to have exactly this behavior, I want to start all the threads and then I wan't the main method to wait until all the threads have finished.

Comment: As I said: the main method waits immediatly for the FIRST thread. And you only call join to the second thread after the first one is done!! You are not calling join on all threads at once in the loop.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. The work of all the threads is independent of each other. So in the first loop I start all the threads one by one. In the second loop I wait for each thread to complete and use its results. So while the main thread is waiting for the first thread to complete all threads are doing their work, after that when main is waiting for the second thread all the remaining threads are doing their work.
Sorry, On second reading I feel that my previous comment was not conveying what I was trying to say/do.

Comment: No, that is not what is happening. You are waiting for the first thread to do their work, but the second and all others continue to run. After the first thread is done your for loop continues but all other threads can perhaps all have finished their work now. Calling join makes o sense for what you want to purpose ... Why don't you just wait till all threads are done?

Comment: If a thread is finished and I call join on it then the program immediately proceeds to the next statement, so by not waiting till all threads are done I am saving time.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using Threads directly it is usually better to use a thread pool like ExecutorService.

```
final String[] parameter=  getParameters(parameters);
final String[] wsdl = getWSDL(wsdlPaths);
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
List<Future<TestStub.ExperimentResponse>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<TestStub.ExperimentResponse>>();
for (int j = 0; j < numServices; j++) {
    final int i = j;
    futures.add(executor.submit(new Callable<TestStub.ExperimentResponse>() {
        @Override
        public TestStub.ExperimentResponse call() throws Exception {
            TestStub stub = new TestStub(wsdl[i]);
            TestStub.Experiment request = new TestStub.Experiment();
            request.setArgs0(model);
            request.setArgs1(property);
            request.setArgs2(parameter[i]);
            return stub.Experiment(request);
        }
    }));
}
for (Future<ExperimentResponse> future : futures) {
    TestStub.ExperimentResponse response = future.get();
    System.out.println("Response: " + response.get_return());
}
executor.shutdown();
```