# MultiThread with one Webservice Client Stub

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, jakarta-ee

Can more than one Thread use same stub instance to invoke webservice call without loosing parallelism?

if each webservice call open a new socket connection, using one stub instance does not allow loosing parallel method invocation.

Any comments will be be appreciated.

I am using Axis, jax-ws, java-ee 6

Comment: IIRC Axis generated stub is not thread safe. You can use however different stub instances for each thread.

Comment: It depends if your stub instance if thread safe...

Comment: which one is thread safe, Axis,CXF JAx-ws?

Comment: does thread safe thread instance quarentee the parallel web service method invocation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950080/are-axis2-generated-stubs-thread-safe this should clear any doubt